# Always Encrypted SQL 2016 and Entity Framework 6: “Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with date”

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2016, asp.net-mvc-5.2, always-encrypted

Current project:

- MVC 5.2
- DotNet 4.6.2
- EF 6
- Identity 2 (modified as per the repository pattern below)
- SQL Server 2016 RTM
- Repository Pattern: [Persistence-Ignorant ASP.NET Identity](http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/14/persistence-ignorant-asp-net-identity-with-patterns-part-1/)
- Always Encrypted column encryption as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/06/04/getting-started-with-always-encrypted/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/08/27/using-always-encrypted-with-entity-framework-6/)
- All SQL as `MapToStoredProcedures();` in `EntityTypeConfiguration`

Unlike the repository pattern tutorial, I was able to push my model to DB. I am not working off of a hand-assembled DB. I did modify the migration as per the two SQL statements in second Always Encrypted link, not surprising also for a birthdate and a Social Security Number.

Because my Entity Framework entities specifies the encrypted fields as such,

```
Property(x => x.Dob).HasColumnOrder(15).HasColumnName("Dob").HasColumnType("Date").IsRequired();
Property(x => x.Sin).HasColumnOrder(16).HasColumnName("Sin").HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(11).IsRequired();
```

I have decorated those two fields in my `User` domain entity in the following way:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
[MaxLength(11)]
public string Sin { get; set; }
```

as per [this comment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/08/27/using-always-encrypted-with-entity-framework-6/#comment-3341). **As a precaution, I have also decorated the same fields in my `IdentityUser.cs` file.**

When I try to push the default administrative user I am trying to create, using this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddAdmin() {
  var user = _userManager.FindByName("email@domain.net");
  if(user == null) {
    user = new IdentityUser() {
      // Other fields
      Dob = new DateTime(1972, 10, 12),
      Sin = "726-261-050",
      // Other fields
    };
    var createUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
    if (createUser.Succeeded) {
      var userId = _userManager.FindByName("email@domain.net").Id;
      var addRole = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, "Admin");
      if (addRole.Succeeded) {
        return View("Index");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Operand type clash: datetime2(7) encrypted with (encryption_type =
>   'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = 'database') is incompatible with
>   date encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED',
>   encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
>   column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = 'database')

which occurs at the `_userManager.CreateAsync()`.

I am completely at a loss as to why this is happening. I have clearly specified `Dob` in `IdentityUser()` as a `Date` field, and not `DateTime2`. The same goes for the raw `User` model/domain and its associated EF entity. The actual DB field is a `Date` field (confirmed this personally), so I can see why the destination is a problem if the source is mysteriously created as a `DateTime2`, even though the `IdentityUser()` `Dob` field is a `Date` as well. Theoretically, a `Date` field in `IdentityUser()` cannot pass on a `DateTime2` to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe EF handles all the date types as datetime2. Changing the column type in SQL server to datetime2 should help. As of now, your only option is to change the datatype of your column to datetime2 in SQL Server, since EF does not have any hooks into parameter generation.

Comment: Somehow the authors of the first Always Encrypted article managed to make it work with Date, they’re just not clear *how*. Besides, a birth date is just the date, it has no time; this makes it more efficient, as it uses less room. And if EF works only with `datetime2`, how does one normally fill a Date field in the DB? Why does an unencrypted Date field not throw the same “incompatible” error when EF passes on the same kind of (unencrypted) data?

Comment: I think I can see where you are coming from -- an unencrypted date insert into a Date field just truncates, whereas if it arrives as a `datetime2` already encrypted, that will throw a big spanner in the works. So how does one do the conversion before the encryption?

Comment: You are correct, for plaintext data, SQL server will do the conversion from datetime2 to datetime. I would create a new table (table 2) with same schema as of the old table, but, change date to datetime2. Keep in mind that table 2 is still plaintext. Then use SQL bulk copy to copy the data from old table to table 2. Then use always encrypted wizard in ssms to encrypt appropriate columns.

Comment: So how can this be scripted through Entity Framework or MVC? Remember, we are talking about active user sign ups where staff create employee portal accounts that include birthdays and SSN’s for account verification purposes.

Comment: Actually you can just try using alter table alter column to change the datatype of the existing column, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx. Of course you are responsible for testing the workflow out in a test environment, before making changes in production environment.

Comment: What I meant was with the bulk copy -- how can that be scripted to occur with every user creation? I had already tried to specify the birthday field as a Date using the alter commands in the Migration of the User table - just like in the tutorials I linked to. That is why I am experiencing this issue in the first place. My problem is with the insertion of new data. Obviously I can create a new table and push the model to DB with a migration, but unless I can script the bulk copy upon user creation all is for naught.

Comment: Pardon me, I do not understand your question. But, if you use alter table alter column on the database with online = ON, the newly inserted rows will automatically be converted.

Comment: My database already has an encrypted `Dob` field with the data type of `date`. I don’t need to alter it to anything else. What I need to do is take the `Dob` from the view model (which is explicitly a `date`, and *not* a `datetime2`) and insert it into the encrypted `Dob` field that has a data type of `date`. Somewhere along the line, that `date` gets auto-converted into `datetime2` against my will just prior to the encryption and insertion, causing the incompatibility.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your sentence "So how does one do the conversion before the encryption?" to mean that you would like to convert the data type of the column before encrypting it with always encrypted. I am not aware of how to force EF to use date instead of datetime2

Comment: @René Kåbis I talked to the EF team and as of now, your only option is to change the datatype of your column to datetime2 in SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah, sucks but I kind of figured that. It’s stupid and short sighted (in light of the Always Encrypted feature of MSSQL 2016), but hey. It does work when the field in MSSQL is `datetime2`.

Comment: Great to hear that it works with datetime2. I have updated the answer to capture the gist of the conversation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138266/discussion-between-nikhil-vithlani-microsoft-and-rene-kabis).

Answer (score 0):

If we don't want to change the datatype of from `datetime` to `datetime2`. because datetime to extend the 7 digit after last decimal.

check by below script. difference b/w datetime and datetime2.

`select * from newdatetimetest
ALTER TABLE newdatetimetest ALTER column mydatetime datetime2`

`select * from newdatetimetest
ALTER TABLE newdatetimetest ALTER column mydatetime datetime`

`select * from newdatetimetest`

You can implement the custom interceptor to change the entityframework datetime2 datatype convert into datetime.

we have successfully implemented and insert the record successfully.

find the reference form below link.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/578

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/pull/1147

Comment: Implemented succesfully.